# Programming pull or push from Git in Java

Tags: java, git, github, push, pull

My question is simple, i want my program to update itself every time it starts making pull from git. Its there a way to do it?

Also I want the program to make push to the repo at git.

Thanks!

Comment: By 'update itself' do you mean recompile?

Comment: yes, well, i think so

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you're asking, but it sounds like you're looking for [Git Hooks](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no simple way to do it. An option can be to build one (or more) OSGi bundles (modules) from your application, listen to file change events ( https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes ), recompile and re-package the changed code using the built-in compiler ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html ) then update the new OSGi bundle.
But probably it won't be an easy ride if you aren't familiar with OSGi.